# Injective holomorphic endomorphism whose image is the complement of a proper analytic subset is surjective.

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, complex-dynamics

Let $f: M \rightarrow M$ be an endomorphism of a connected complex manifold $M$. Assume that $f(M)$ is a dense open set in $M$ and that $M \setminus f(M)$ is an analytic subset of $M$

Question: Can I deduce that if $f$ is injective then $f$ is surjective, thus biholomorphic?

*This is true when $M$ is one dimensional (this is false,see edit)* i.e. a Riemann surface but I don't know whether it is still true in higher dimension. In another category like algebraic varieties with regular morphisms, it is also true thanks to Ax-Grothendieck theorem.

Edit: This is not true thanks to the answer of Moishe. My argument is that $M$ and $f(M)$ are biholomorphic and $f(M)$ is punctured Riemann surface obtained from $M$. If $M$ is finite type then this is impossible but if $M$ is finite type (like $\mathbb{C}$ removed $\mathbb{N}$ then it is possible).

Comment: This is false even in 1-dimensional case (when $M$ is a unit disk: think of the Riemann mapping theorem).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you. I edited the question. Open dense is not that strong condition. If I replace the condition is that $M \setminus f(M)$ is an analytic set then it is true in 1-dimensional by using fundamental groups since proper analytic sets in 1-dimensional are discrete sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already false for Riemann surfaces: Consider $M$ equal to ${\mathbb C}$ with the set of natural numbers removed and let $f(z)=z-1$; $f(M)\subset M$ and the complement $M - f(M)$ is a singleton.